# (Ruby) Error: `set_encoding': can't convert String to Hash in sinatra file (base.rb, line 1760)

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, sass, haml

I'm trying to run an example app from github. their app runs fine. which means that my setup is wrong, but I don't know what it is. this is my first time trying ruby.

what I did: 
1- downloaded the code from github 
2- made a gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "2.0.0"
gem "sinatra", "1.4.4"
gem "haml", "4.0.3"
gem "sass", "3.2.12"
```

3- ran bundle install 
4- when I run my .rb file (on heroku or on my computer), I get this error everytime:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1760:in `set_encoding': can't convert String to Hash (String#to_hash gives Symbol) (TypeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1760:in `block in detect_rack_handler'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1758:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1758:in `detect_rack_handler'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1420:in `run!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/main.rb:25:in `block in <module:Sinatra>'
```

--> I should signal that the github repo I'm trying to run is old (hasn't been touched since 2010)

Comment: could you define gems with no specific versions in the `Gemfile`?

Comment: yes, tried it, with no success.

Comment: have you tried other ruby?

Comment: ok, just tried it. it gives a different error with it: 

2013-12-12T11:30:05.284194+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/main.rb:11:in `expand_path': can't convert Symbol to String (Symbol#to_str gives Symbol) (TypeError)

Comment: (that actually seemed like a good idea because I just checked and that app hasn't been touched on github since 2010.)

Comment: yes, I think you need to fix it, to support newer version of sinatra etc. Or may be just select proper version of sinatra/etc with which the app worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. so it turns out it wasn't my setup. (I tried using gems and ruby versions from 2009 and it didn't make the error go away either.)

I narrowed it down by gradually commenting things out in the script (since ruby wouldn't give me a line in my own files, only in sinatra files, I thought at first it wasn't due to my code).

--> it was a single line of code that, now that I commented it out in my script, made the error disappear forever with seemingly no negative side effects. (see code below).

If someone can briefly comment on that method (is it some kind of sinatra framework callback, for error handling a call to a nonexistent method? I assume this since it's never called in my files!) and why it could cause the error described in the question, I will pick their answer, otherwise I will pick this (my) answer. (just write anything you know or can find about this method and I'll pick your answer, Thanks).

```
def method_missing(methId)
  method_name=methId.id2name.intern
  if @lists.respond_to? method_name
    @lists.send(method_name).pick
  else
    # method_name # line that caused the error in the sinatra source files.
  end
end
```

================================================

so here's my own quick research on method_missing ... trying to learn ruby a bit here:

some info about method_missing: 
http://www.alfajango.com/blog/method_missing-a-rubyists-beautiful-mistress/#/when-to-use-method-missing 
http://rubylearning.com/blog/2010/10/07/do-you-know-rubys-chainsaw-method/

second link is a great intro.
basically method_missing is, yes, a kind of error handler for calling nonexistent methods. it's a ruby language thing (it calls method_missing when it can't find the method). so it's not tied to a framework, just to ruby.

besides simple error handling, one common usage for it is to be able define actions according to the (non-existent) method name (make up actions based on the nonexistent method name!), for example in the case where you have a great number of methods that do very repetitive things and you can deduce/base their behavior on their name.

a way to limit your pool of "methods you're going to make up behavior for, on the spot" is to have an if with a regular expression match (or in our case a match in a predefined list of items). if it's not matched, then you can for example throw an exception yourself or just return to see what happens next in the calling code.

so here in our code:

```
if the method name doesnt exist, they check if it exists in a list and act accordingly (they return a list, picked among @lists).
but if it is not found in @lists … they return that very method name, a string, that we didnt have a match for.
```

...but now the question is: --> how is the calling code dealing with that return value? (obviously not well, it seems to expect a hash or an array, not a method name string) a safe way to deal with "not finding a match for your nonexistent method" is to call super, to resume normal execution of the calling code (according to first link).

so one question remains: was it a good idea to return the method name? would returning the method name ever work? or was it really wrong, and super (or nothing) should be put in its place?

… my temporary conclusion is that --> you shouldn't return a list *sometimes* and a string *some other times*. so it would be a plain mistake, that surprisingly never caused problems or was never found in the original repo...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is an error in the used gem "sinatra".

Try to change the gemfile like this (without giving explicit version number), so that the application installs the latest version of the gems.

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "2.0.0"
gem "sinatra"
gem "haml"
gem "sass"
```

Probably there is a newer version of the sinatra gem.

Comment: ok, just tried it. it didn't download anything new (it's all using, using, etc. -- no installing). and of course I still get the error...

Comment: I saw in the sinatra code that it has also external dependencies. Probably you could add gem "rack" to the gemfile. How did you run the file? Like this (as shown on sinatra page)?
$ gem install sinatra
$ ruby yourfile.rb
== Sinatra has taken the stage ...
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567

Comment: I tried adding gem "rack" in the gem file, but no success (rack was already automatically downloaded by bundle install with sinatra). I got sinatra by making the gemfile and then running: sudo bundle install, then I ran the script in the command line with: ruby script.rb (... now that I changed the ruby version to 1.9.2 a few minutes ago I can only run it on heroku, but before I was using 2.0.0)

Comment: What you could try also is to use an older version of Sinatra, since you said the app is quite old.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I did. but still the error was there.